# why doesn't cURL process range when there's some other data in URL after stated range

Tags: curl, curl-commandline

why doesn't cURL process range when there's some other data posted after the range? Example -- I wanna post 400 messages like this:

```
curl -X POST -d "$post_data" "http://www.example.com/post_id=[1-400]&message[body]=Hello
```

However, the cUrl doesn't post them - only after I remove the ''&message[body]=Hello' part - curl is able to process request with blank messages. How can I write the command so that curl will process the range with included message also?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`[]` has a special meaning at curl. Specially when you are defining a range(i.e. the one you are already using at the command).

Escape `[]` using `\` character. See below:

```
curl -X POST -d "$post_data" "http://www.example.com/post_id=[1-400]&message\[body\]=Hello
                                                                            ^     ^
```